# How to Debug .Net Core Application Running on Minikube from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, minikube

I have made a .Net Core Web Application and deployed it on container running on Minikube VM. I want to debug that app, How can I do it using Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update for Visual Studio 2019: https://link.medium.com/rGycPY6NGdb

---

You can use [vsdbg](https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/What-is-CLRDBG) to debug any remote dotnet core process on Linux. Kubernetes Minikube uses Docker underneath and Docker container is in fact something like a Linux VM.
I wrote a [post](https://medium.com/@pavel.agarkov/debugging-asp-net-core-app-running-in-kubernetes-minikube-from-visual-studio-2017-on-windows-6671ddc23d93) about this on Medium.com if you need more details.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to work in VS2019 but I get the following error `unexpected CLRDBG output from command "-gdb-set auto-solib-add on"`. I believe this occurs after the debugger tries to attatch to the pod but other than that I'm in the dark. I'm using vsdbg version 16.0.20419.1 since that's the latest version that supported the `--attach` argument if that matters. In Powershell it does connect correctly and displays a lot of information similar to what you have shown in the blog post.

Comment: i haven't used this since then so you should probably post this as a separate question

Comment: Newest vsdbg download does not support the `--attach` flag.