# How do I set up Visual Studio 2017 to debug containers in local Kubernetes cluster instead of docker-compose environment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, visual-studio-2017

I have a local kubernetes cluster, which I set up with Docker Desktop. I would like to debug with Visual Studio and the local Kubernetes clusters instead of with the docker-compose containers.

How might I configure Visual Studio to do interactive debugging on the alternative (Kubernetes) environment, rather than the out-of-the-box one created using docker-compose?

Comment: i guess you cannt do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [#46361844](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361844/how-to-debug-net-core-application-running-on-minikube-from-visual-studio-2017)